# How to call method using span id in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I have function as follows:

```
Mask (sender) { 
var error= false;
        var regex = '^[0-9]+,[0-9][0-9]$'; 
    
          if(!($(sender).val().match(regex))) {   
              error = true;
        }   
}
```

HTML

```
<input name="mf1234" value="" id="mf1234" onblur="Mask(this)"/>
<span class="comment" id="mf1234" class="sssnnn"></span>
```

I am calling `onBlur` using (`this`), but if I want to call it by Mask (`this.id`) with span id, how can I change my method code?

Comment: Your IDs for the INPUT and SPAN tag are the same. IDs must be unique in the DOM.

Comment: I want as jquery object not the DOM thats why i have same id's

Comment: @SomiMeer, it doesn't *matter* what you want to use the `id`s *for*, they ***must*** be unique within the document (seriously: it's [in the HTML rules/spec from the W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function Mask (senderID) {
   var error= false;
    var regex = '^[0-9]+,[0-9][0-9]$'; 

    if(!($("#" + senderID).val().match(regex))) {   
        error = true;
    } 
}
```

JQuery takes the CSS selector values, so any ID's need to be represented as #idValue
`<div id='MyId'>` would be called in jQuery as `$("#MyId")`

So if you plan on passing `Mask(this.id)` to `function Mask (senderID)` you need to call `$("#" + senderID)`

You can call this from the HTML like so, however inline Javascript is not recommended. 
Look into Code Seperation.

```
<input name="mf1234" value="" id="mf1234" onblur="Mask(this.id)"/>
<span class="comment" id="mf1234_comment" class="sssnnn"></span>
```

Here is the *better* solution...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mf1234").bind("blur", function() {
        var error = false;
        var regex = '^[0-9]+,[0-9][0-9]$';
        if (!($(this).val().match(regex))) {
            error = true;
        }
        console.log(error);
    });
});
```

attach your events in the javascript.. this avoids inline javascript and promotes code separation. This will aid you in Maintainability and Readability

ohh and then you html will look like this

```
<input name="mf1234" value="" id="mf1234" />
<span class="comment" id="mf1234_comment" class="sssnnn"></span>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/NCwF3/

Comment: Why is this downvoted? This does EXACTLY what the OP asked for.

Comment: You should write something to explain what you're doing differently. Your answer might be correct, but it's not as helpful as it could be.

Comment: @Rob, thats just apples and oranges.. Whether the OP passes this or this.id was ambiguous.

Comment: I have improved your answer. The issue ws caused by something else: The input element has the same ID as the span element.

Comment: and i have changed it back.. not out of spite. just because I believe if the OP asks how to pass this.id, I should show how to pass and use this.id

Comment: @SomiMeer, you also need to take heed the point that you have multiple elements with the same ID value. ID values must be unique, use classes if you want to define rules for a group of elements.

Comment: @HollySeltner: I did downvote it. It contained single definition of the function, without any comments and without HTML, thus it was definitely not what OP wanted. Applying it would not help OP, unless he would guess what he must do in addition to what you posted.

Comment: for example if i change span id as mf1234mm then

Comment: sorry i meant for example if i want to change to span class as mf1234m . instead of calling on span id then how to change in code . text box id and span class is almost same but span class name have one Extra 'm' with that . in this case how to do

Comment: @HollySeltner: Did you just add my solution and mention this is a better one (quote: " _Here is the better solution..._ ")? ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following (and check [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cxs6S/)):

```
$('input[name="mf1234"]').blur(function(){
    var error= false;
    var regex = RegExp('^[0-9]+,[0-9][0-9]$'); 

    if(!($(this).val().match(regex))) {   
        error = true;
        alert('error');
    } else {
        alert('no error');
    }
});
```

It does not use inline JavaScript, but if you insist on using predefined function (`Mask()`), you can just call it from inside the `.blur()`.

Comment: but my requirement is to call like onblur = Mask(this.id)